# Regex eclipse search/replace

Tags: regex, eclipse

i'm trying to find an regex for code cleanup.

i want to cut of all tabs withoput any character following.

```
\t+\n
```

Does not work for me:/

Eclipse returns everytime "String not found"

is the regex wrong?

greetings

Answer (score 1):

You want to use:

```
\t+$
```

Comment: strange, it seem it works with the strg+h search, but not with the strg+f search:/